# Create a many to many relationship (EF code first) where each side of relationship is the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possibly overthinking this, but I am trying to create the following relationship. I have an Organization object. Each organization can have many AuthorizedThirdParties. AuthorizedThirdParties are Organizations as well. How do I accomplish this? For some context. An authorized 3rd party is a way of saying 'this particular organization (that is not me) can access certain information about my organization'.

The Organization model (trimmed for brevity):

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> AuthorizedThirdParties { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking of doing some fluent API stuff, but can't seem to figure out how. I have is set up for a few other m2m relationships, but each of those are referencing different models (like Organization and User).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't overthinking it. Data structures are complicated and should be done right. The data structure you are describing is a `graph`. There are many ways to represent a graph. Among them are:

- Adjacency list
- Incidence list
- Adjacency matrix
- Incidence matrix

Each have their own benefits and weaknesses based one your expected use. For a starting point, hit wikipedia:

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29)

Best thing to do is to research how to represent the data and how to store the data, here is a starting links:

- http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/Graphs.html

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship is many-to-many (an organization can have many `AuthorizedThirdParties` and an organization can be an authorized third party for many other organizations) you would just use a standard mapping. There is nothing special whether the target entity is the same or different:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
    .HasMany(o => o.AuthorizedThirdParties)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("AuthorizedThirdPartyMap");
        m.MapLeftKey("OrganizationId");
        m.MapRightKey("AuthorizedThirdPartyId");
    });
```